# Getting External File/Data Directories for other apps

Tags: android, android-applicationinfo

I need the External Data directory paths for other apps. I know the method for the app I am currently developing. But is there any way to get the External Data Dir paths for other apps?

For example:
getExternalFilesDirs("type") gives the external data dirs for my app, but I need this for other apps.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that on Android Q and higher, it looks like you will not be allowed to access other apps' files this way.

Comment: this question is pointless (unless knowing which directory one is looking for), because they may create whatever directory they want - without having to register it anywhere.

Comment: I am talking about Something like "Android/data/<pkg_name>" on internal storage and sd card. I mean the files returned by getExternalFilesDirs("type").